# angular field in custom form control getting delayed updates

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a custom input field in Angular.  My custom control has an @Input() that is bound to the value of the input field.  When I try to use it in a form, I can see that writeValue is being called, but the new value does not display until I call writeValue again.  The normal input field does not do this.  Any idea what I am doing wrong?

my control's HTML (vdsfield.component.html):

```
<input (input)="handleFieldChange($event)"
       [type]="inputType" [disabled]="disabled"
       [placeholder]="placeholder"
       [value]="value"/>
<span *ngIf="error" class="error-icon"><span>!</span></span>
```

The typescript:

```
import {Component, forwardRef, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  // tslint:disable-next-line:component-selector
  selector: 'vds-field',
  templateUrl: './vdsfield.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./vdsfield.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => VDSFieldComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class VDSFieldComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

  @Input() placeholder: string;
  @Input() value: string;
  @Input() disabled: boolean;
  @Input() inputType = 'text';
  @Input() error = false;

  constructor() { }

  propagateChange = (_: any) => {};

  handleFieldChange(e) {
    this.value = e.target.value;
    console.log('field changed');
    this.propagateChange(this.value);
  }

  writeValue(obj: any): void {
    if (obj !== undefined) {
      this.value = obj;
      console.log('Writing value:' + obj);
    }
  }

  registerOnChange(fn) {
    this.propagateChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn) {
  }
}
```

When I change the model, I can see that writeValue is being called with the new value via the console.log, but the inner  control does not update.  When I set the value again, the previous value is drawn.  If I use a normal  field in the form instead of my custom control, it does not do this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like change detection issue which is common for angular forms where it can often feel like you are fighting the unidirectional data flow. Can you stick this in a stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

*Call the handleFieldChange function in the last position*

**use this block of code**

```
<input [type]="inputType" [disabled]="disabled"
   [placeholder]="placeholder"
   [value]="value" 
   (input)="handleFieldChange($event)" />
<span *ngIf="error" class="error-icon"><span>!</span></span>
```

**instead of**

```
<input (input)="handleFieldChange($event)"
   [type]="inputType" [disabled]="disabled"
   [placeholder]="placeholder"
   [value]="value"/>
<span *ngIf="error" class="error-icon"><span>!</span></span>
```